# How to crop a resized image in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, image-processing

I am trying to resize an image in CSS and HTML- this is my current CSS code I use to resize an image to its desired size:

```
.resize-image {
    border:1px solid #021a40;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 1442px;
}
```

Using that CSS, how would I crop any image so that only the first 250 px, or 20%, etc. of the image shows up? Here's what I mean:

[image: The area with the arrow is the part I want to remove- I only want to keep the top quarter of the picture]

**The area with the arrow is the part I want to remove- I only want to keep the top quarter of the picture.**  How would I accomplish this in CSS or HTML?

EDIT: This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.resize-image {
    border:1px solid #021a40;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 1442px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class= "img-container">
    <img class = "resize-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/DJPXuPZ.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `overflow` to the parent and set its `height` to the amount you wish to ***crop***.

```css
.resize-image {
  border: 1px solid #021a40;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 1442px;
}

.img-container {
  width: auto;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img class="resize-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/DJPXuPZ.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `height` and `overflow: hidden` on parent `div`
Hope! it works

```css
.img-container{
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.resize-image {
    border:1px solid #021a40;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div class= "img-container">
    <img class = "resize-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/DJPXuPZ.png">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```